# How to read the value from another form and assign it to a field in another form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a main form. And I have a text field named text123. when the user clicks the text123, it opens another form. In this new form there is two controls. one is a combo box named cmb1 and another is a textfield named text456. when the user selects an option from the combo box the lookup value is placed in the textfield on the form.

now I have an appen button on this form. How do I pass the value of the text456 in the second form to the text123 on the previous form when I click on the append buton.

an example of the second form is shown below:
[image]

Comment: `Forms!MainForm.text123.Value = Me.text456.Value`?

Comment: I will test it and see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the correct reference is to open both forms.
Then go select the form from which you want to update the other form.
Select a field and open in Properties Control Source and click on the ...

Then you will see the following Expression Builder window. In that window click on the + in front of Loaded Forms. Then you can select any control from any open form.
This gives you the exact syntax you need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just change
Forms!MainForm.text123.Value = Me.text456.Value
to
Forms!MainForm**!**text123.Value = Me.text456.Value

Comment: this answer feels low quality.  It is technically correct but is mostly just a copy of a much older comment.  Value is unnecessary.  Meanwhile the other answer being a general method is of higher quality.  finally and unfairly there is no mention of using public methods instead which gives much greater robustness and flexibility.